# Poor performance on MKMapView clustering in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I've been using third-party libraries for handling markers clustering. Since iOS 11 has its own implementation, I've decided to move on and remove third-party libraries on behalf "native" implementation.

I've downloaded the example app from WWDC 2017 and follow the same steps, so:

- Connect `MKMapView` Outlet
- Implement `MKAnnotation` protocol for my model
- Create a `MKMarkerAnnotationView` for marker's view
- Create a `MKMarkerAnnotationView` for cluster's view
- Register both annotations on my mapView reference with register(`_:forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:`) function
- Add annotations to my map

However, while using third-party libraries everything was fine, with this method I get a very poor performance when I pan on my mapView and change region. CPU usage raises up to 90% while memory seems to stay stable, and I feel delay in moving and sometimes even app crashes. I'm loading about 600 annotations.

Any suggestion?

Here is the code:

```
class MapViewClusteringViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
  private var databaseService: LocalDataService!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.register(StopMarker.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
    mapView.register(StopCluster.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    databaseService.fetchMarkers { markers in
      mapView.addAnnotation(markers)
    }
  }
}

class StopMarker: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
  override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
      clusteringIdentifier = "busStopCluster"
      subtitleVisibility = .adaptive
      markerTintColor = .red
    }
  }
}

class StopCluster: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
  override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    displayPriority = .defaultHigh
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
      if let cluster = newValue as? MKClusterAnnotation {
        markerTintColor = .green
        glyphText = "\(cluster.memberAnnotations.count)"
      }
    }
  }
}

class StopAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
  var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  var title: String?

  init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any code that gets invoked after region change? Do you get poor performance on the device or in the simulator?

Comment: I tried on iPhone SE and iPhone 7, both with poor performance, and I don't do anything after region changes

Comment: Do you have the annotations as "animated" as they drop?

Comment: Is your 'databaseService.fetchMarkers' performed on the background thread? Maybe you are performing too many computations on the main thread? What does debugging in Instruments say?

Comment: Annotations doesn't have any animation and I perform fetching on background thread

Comment: MapKit is very badly optimized. It renders all pins (even if its 10k) to animate clustering. Note that you set `clusteringIdentifier` on `MKAnnotationView` not on `MKAnnotation` ‍♂️. Therefore, reusable annotations are useless and clustering is useless. To fix this problem you need a quad tree algorithm and implement own clustering. Fortunately, there is an implementation that has it. It's old but it's only an algorithm so it's still working well: https://github.com/efremidze/Cluster

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkclusterannotation), you can read:

> Do not create instances of this class yourself. MapKit automatically creates cluster annotations when two or more annotation views become grouped too closely together on the map surface.

You may try without creating instance of this class by yourself.

Comment: I do not create any instance by myself. I just define a `MKMarkerAnnotationView` subclass to be used as cluster when map needs it. And then, I register that class for `MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier` and let mapkit do it's job. Forget the initializers, you can remove it. And it works, but the performance with 600 markers is slow and poor

Comment: If you got rendering issue when using a lot of markers you may start to think about using a non-native method, you may use leaflet (https://leafletjs.com/) and use markercluster plugin (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)